# Ubuntu open a chromium in kiosk mode and disable graphical environment

Tags: gnome, chromium

I want to use chromium in kiosk mode. I know I can do this in `.xinitrc` file. How can I disable all graphic environment like unity, lxde et.c. to decrease loading and increase performance of my system?